# How to get top 30 count record and rest total using two dimension in mdx

Tags: mdx

I'm able to get the top 30 records based on Airline and DMA but I'm unable to sum up the rest of the records.

```
select {[Measures].[Sum]} on columns,
  Generate({[V Airline].[Airline Ds].members},
         {TopCount(Order(
            HIERARCHIZE(crossjoin([V Airline].[Airline Ds].currentmember ,
                                  [v RPTS TRNS Visits].[DMA Ds].members)),
            [Measures].[Sum],BDESC),30,[Measures].[Sum])}) 
on rows from [Cube_ATA] 
where ([v RPTS TRNS Visits].[Country Cd].&[USA])
```

It's retrieving top 30 records. How to sum up the remaining records?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144900.aspx) function. Declare your TopCount set then

```
EXCEPT([FULLSET], [TOPCOUNT_SET])
```

will return you the remaining records.